# Paginate Assets

Tags: pagination, gallery

I am setting up a photo gallery and below is what I have right now. My problem is when I go the next page /2 it says that entry does not exist. I have routes set up as /gallery/slug/*, and pointing to this template.

Is there a way to paginate images like this?

```
 {% paginate entry.images.limit(20) as imagesOnPage %}
  {% for image in imagesOnPage %}
    <div class="thumb col-1-4">
        <a href="{{ image.getUrl() }}" data-fresco-group="{{ entry.id }}" data-fresco-caption="{{ image.title }}" title="{{ image.title }}" class="fresco">
                <img src="{{ image.getUrl('galleryThumbnail') }}" title="{{ image.title }}" alt="{{ image.title }}">
          </a>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}

  <div class="pagination">
    {% if paginate.prevUrl %}<a href="{{ paginate.prevUrl }}" class="prev">◄</a>{% endif %}

    {% for page, url in paginate.getPrevUrls(5) %}
        <a href="{{ url }}">{{ page }}</a>
    {% endfor %}

    <span class="current">{{ paginate.currentPage }}</span>

    {% for page, url in paginate.getNextUrls(5)  %}
        <a href="{{ url }}" class="page-numbers">{{ page }}</a>
    {% endfor %}

    {% if paginate.nextUrl %}<a href="{{ paginate.nextUrl }}" class="next">►</a>{% endif %}

  </div>
{% endpaginate %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should actually go to /p2 - this has been a bug in some 2.4 releases, so can you tell me if you are on the latest version?

Comment: Yup, you're right, there was one update, and after I ran that it started working. before the update the links were pointing to /2 and now with build 2.4.2669 they point to /p2. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The `{% paginate %}` tag requires the ElementCriteriaModel to be passed through first.

Since you were requesting `entry.images.limit(20)` to be paginated, I suspect you have your images set up within a single images asset. Instead you will need to set up your images within a channel or structure if you would like Craft to paginate the gallery between several pages.

This hasn't been tested, although spot the differences with the inclusion of the `craft` prefix within the ElementCriteriaModel.

```
{% paginate craft.entries.section("gallery").limit(20) as imagesOnPage %}

    {% for entry in imagesOnPage %}
        <div class="thumb col-1-4">
<a href="{{ entry.image.getUrl() }}" data-fresco-group="{{ entry.id }}" data-fresco-caption="{{ entry.image.title }}" title="{{ entry.image.title }}" class="fresco">
                <img src="{{ entry.image.getUrl('galleryThumbnail') }}" title="{{ entry.image.title }}" alt="{{ entry.image.title }}">
            </a>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}

  <div class="pagination">
    {% if paginate.prevUrl %}<a href="{{ paginate.prevUrl }}" class="prev">◄</a>{% endif %}

    {% for page, url in paginate.getPrevUrls(5) %}
        <a href="{{ url }}">{{ page }}</a>
    {% endfor %}

    <span class="current">{{ paginate.currentPage }}</span>

    {% for page, url in paginate.getNextUrls(5)  %}
        <a href="{{ url }}" class="page-numbers">{{ page }}</a>
    {% endfor %}

    {% if paginate.nextUrl %}<a href="{{ paginate.nextUrl }}" class="next">►</a>{% endif %}

  </div>
{% endpaginate %}`
```

Sources: http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/paginate,
http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel

Comment: entry.images.limit(20) is an ElementCriteriaModel just as well